# Paris public transport apps: Île-de-France Mobilités vs. Bonjour RATP

Tags: tickets, public-transport, france, applications, paris

I'm moving to Paris in few weeks and currently checking useful apps for daily use. Can you please advise what is the best app to use for public transport in Paris?

I am confused between the two apps [Île-de-France Mobilités](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.applidium.vianavigo) and [Bonjour RATP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fabernovel.ratp).
I downloaded both apps on my phone and tried the features of each app and they looked the same to me.
Any idea please which one is more reliable based on your experience? Thank you very much.

Comment: Not sure if it's still the case, but the RATP app had an awful bias towards buses in many cases, which gave results quite far from reality, both in terms of frequency/wait times and speed/time to destination. I personally much prefer to use Google Maps, and usually only use the RATP app to look up disruptions (which often aren't quite up to date either). Never used the IDFM app, though.

Comment: Both apps seem to cover a wide variety of transport modalities. There may be small differences in services you're less likely to use (e.g. IdFM mentions car sharing but I can't see anything about that on RATP), so it might depend exactly what you are planning on doing in Paris. I also see comments about poor English language support on IdFM but if you're moving to Paris I assume that's not an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The differences between IDF Mobilités and Bonjour RATP are very slim and will likely never be a deal-breaker.

As a parisian local, I would recommend [Citymapper](https://citymapper.com/) (not sponsored) which I use daily.

From a UI/UX perspective it's the better of the bunch, having tried all three. But it is really subjective.

For coverage, Citymapper has the same as both other apps but has coverage on all the non-IDFM (IDFM being the authority over Metro, RER, Bus...) transport, like bikes, e-scooters, Uber (and other competing driver apps) all-in-one app. Bonjour RATP now does also support all e-scooters brands and a Marcel (a Uber competitor) too

Comment: Do both apps allow you buy and validate fare?

Comment: @jeffmaher Both apps (+ SNCF Connect) allow you to buy and validate fares